# Leaflet WMTS layer

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I would like to start using Leaflet instead of OpenLayers, but I can't find a way to load WMTS layer into the map. Is that possible with Leaflet, or do I have to stick with OL? I haven't found anything related to this topic.

Comment: You can use the IGN L.TileLayer.WMTS class.  See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466634/using-leaflet-with-wmts-server

Answer (score 4):

Technically wmts could be use as a tilelayer, but will have to figure out your Tiling structure. A constructor for a layer could look something like this:

```
 L.tileLayer('<ServiceRoot>?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=[version]&Layer=[layername]&Format=image/png&TileMatrixSet[MatrixsetName]=&TileMatrix={z}&TileRow={x}&TileCol={y}').addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a hint, I've tried  `var zm = L.tileLayer('http://geoportal-zm0.cuzk.cz/WMTS_ZM/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&Layer=zm&TileMatrixSet=openlayerssphericalmercator:epsg:900913&TILEMATRIX={z}&TILEROW={x}&TILECOL={y}&FORMAT=image/png');` with no success. No request is being sent to the server. But if I visit wmts [directly](http://geoportal-zm0.cuzk.cz/WMTS_ZM/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&Layer=zm&Format=image/png&TileMatrixSet=openlayerssphericalmercator:epsg:900913&TILEMATRIX=1&TILEROW=1&TILECOL=1&style=default), it works.

Comment: have you added it to the map with addTo()?

Comment: this worked for me with a couple of fixes: col is the X and row is the Y and TileMatrixSet has the equals sign after the parameter here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use WMTS, if you're reading from GeoServer. GeoServer does the same caching for both WMTS and WMS, so just using a Leaflet WMS reader will work fine.

Comment: True! Unfortunately we can't all be using geoserver all the time.....sad times.